# Weak-$\star$ Convergence in $L_1$

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-topology

Let

- $(X,d)$ be a complete separable metric space;
- $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$;
- $(f_n),(g_n)\subset L_1(X,\mu)$ be sequences of non-negative uniformly bounded sequences, bounded by $1$, i.e. for all $x\in X$ and for all $n$ we have

$$0\leq f_n(x),g_n(x)\leq 1,$$
$$||f_n||_1, ||g_n||_1\leq 1.$$

Suppose that
$$f_n \rightarrow_{w^*}  f\in L_1(X,\mu)$$
$$g_n \rightarrow_{w^*}  g\in L_1(X,\mu)$$
$$f_n\times g_n\rightarrow_{w^*} F\in L_1(X,\mu)$$

Now the question is: is it true that
$$F=f\times g?$$

(Throughout, $\times$ denotes pointwise multiplication.)

**Discussion:** If, under these assumptions, one can show that one can extract a subsequence that is almost surely convergent, then the result follows.

Comment: what does the sign $\times $ indicate here? The space $L_1$ is not closed under multiplication, in general.

Comment: Hi. This is pointwise multiplication. I know this is not always the case. But in the given problem, obviously, their pointwise product is again in $L_1$ as the functions are bounded uniformly by $1$ for each $x$

Comment: Sorry, could you remind me how weak-* convergence in $L_1$ is defined?

Comment: Hi, weak-$*$ means:
$$\int_X f_n(x)\phi(x) d\mu(x)\to \int_X f(x)\phi(x) d\mu(x)\quad \forall \phi\in C_b(X)$$
It is actually the topology from duality between $M(X)$ and $C_b(X)$ by considering $L_1(X)$ as a subspace of $M(X)$

Answer (score 3):

No. Take the underlying probability space to be $[0,1]$ with the uniform distribution. For each $n$, divide the unit interval into $2^n$ subintervals of equal length and number them consecutively. Let $f_n$ be the indicator function of the odd-numbered intervals and $g_n$ the indicator function of the even-numbered intervals. Then $f_n\times g_n=0$ for all $n$ and so is $F$. But the sequences $\langle f_n\rangle$ and $\langle g_n\rangle$ have the same weak-$\star$ limit, the function with constant value $1/2$ and $1/2\times 1/2=1/4\neq 0$ .

Comment: What if we have all these in terms of $L_\infty$ instead of $L_1$?

Comment: @Kafka, I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean if the sequences $f_n$, $g_n$ belong to $L_\infty$ and are weak-star convergent to $f$ and $g$ respectively, and the their pointwise multiplication $f_ng_n$ converges to $F$ in weak star sense in $L_\infty$ can we say $fg=F$?. You see, in the statement, I wrote these functions are in $L_1$. But let say they are in $L_\infty$ with all uniform bound described above. Now, can we deduce $fg=F$?

Comment: All the functions in my example are bounded.